# Swap out App Delegate from Objective-C to Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates

I am looking to replace my Objective-c App delegate from to a Swift App-Delegate.

I have converted a great deal of code already in Swift, looking to finally covert the App Delegate.

I've been researching around the internet and haven't found any really concrete information to go about achieving this so I'd figure it might be helpful to create a StackOverFlow question regarding the topic.

Looks like I can create a new App Delegate from the File -> New File menu in Xcode.

But **how does the complier know** to pick the Swift App Delegate or the Objective-C App Delegate?

I've looked around in the build settings; haven't really discovered anything that would be pointing to this delegate (Other than the build phases).

Comment: Would be easier to start a new target that's swift and work it from there. You shouldn't have a .m and .swift of same class linked to the same target otherwise you'll get a duplicate symbol error from the compiler. Check out this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/Migration.html)

Comment: Just an FYI As of 2020, developer doc ["Migrating Your Objective-C Code to Swift"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/migrating_your_objective-c_code_to_swift) says you don't have to delete the .m files; instead: >Once you migrate a class to Swift, you must remove the corresponding .m file from the target before building to avoid a duplicate symbol error.

Answer (score 3):

In Obj-C file `main.m` is the enter point to a program. In this file you tell which class will be the app delegate by calling `UIApplicationMain` function:

```
UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

In Swift you can use `@UIApplicationMain` [attribute](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html) for your AppDelegate class to indicate enter point and delegate class. Or you can create `main.swift` file.

You can't have both `main.m` and `main.swift` (or app delegate class with `@UIApplicationMain` attribute) in same project. In this case you will get linker error.

So to switch to Swift implementation of your app delegate you need mark it with attribute, then remove old Obj-C class and `main.m` file. Or you need to specify new class in `main.m` file.

Comment: note, if you delete the main.m file you also need to remove it from Compile Sources. Select your Target, go to Build Phases tab and Compile Sources to remove it

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this project was constructed as an Objective-C project, you should have a main.m file that includes a call to `UIApplicationMain`.  The final parameter in that call specifies the application delegate class name.